# Las views muestran el color de fondo teniendo ancho y alto en 0dp, ¿No deberia haber desborde ademas?

Tags: android, android-layout

Estoy aprendiendo a construir layouts en android

Estoy aprendiendo `LinearLayout`, estaba viendo el como  repartir el espacio sobrante con la propiedad `layout_weight`.

Tengo este codigo XML

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Tom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:background="#360730"/>

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="#11397a"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Tim"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="#e31bcc"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Todd"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Obtengo este resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se supone que el espacio sobrante, se trata del espacio sobrante del ancho, los `TextView` tienen 0dp de alto, el texto no debería mostrarse, el `background` de cada `TextView` menos porque el alto es 0dp

- Quería saber ¿que es lo que causa que los `TextView` se dibujen como
  si su alto siguiera siendo `wrap_content` en lugar de 0dp?. el
  background ni siquiera deberia de mostrarse.
- ¿que ocurre cuando una View no tiene las
  dimensiones suficientes para que su contenido alcance dentro de esta?.

Tengo experiencia con CSS, con la propiedad `overflow` puedes hacer que el contenido este visible, o que este oculto o que haya barras de scroll para que se pueda ver el contenido desbordado, pero no se como ocurre en android.

Podría estar probando para ver que sucede pero me gustaría tener una base teórica.

Answer (score 0):

Si defines en los `TextView` los atributos `android:layout_width="0dp"` y  `android:layout_height="0dp"` no implica que va a desaparecer la vista.

En este caso debes si deseas desaparecer la vista y que esta no use un espacio debes usar el atributo y valor:

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

programaticamente serìa:

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

y para aparecer la vista nuevamente:

```
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Visibility

Comment: ese código que acabas de colocar  y su funcionamiento es extraño porque a mi me funciona exactamente como debe funcionar , es decir, los textview no se ven porque estan a 0dp sus dimensiones..., revisa que no tengas algún código en el archivo java o kt que cambie las dimensiones de los textview